# What kind of cultures would develop on a moon of a gas giant?

Tags: astronomy, orbital-mechanics, civilization, time-keeping, mythology

Picture yourself a gas giant which has a system of many moons. on the probably closest moon, which has an atmosphere close to earth's, its orbital period is close to earth's rotation period (Mimas of Saturn is the closest to this) and is tidally locked to the planet, there is a life. What kind of cultures will raise on its surface? Would the planet be the main god of the cultures who raised on the side that face to the planet? How would the cultures that raised away from the planet and could never see it will tell for their selves on the moons they see moving in such a way at the sky? Our calendar is 12 months a year because of our only simple big moon. How their complex calendar would be built?

Would there be any ceremonies and holidays on the side faced to the planet while it eclipsing the sun(or when the moon eclipsing the sun on the planet and the people on that side seeing the shadow of their moon of it?)

Is there any software or tool that I could model this system and see their skies from the surface and think for myself what would I think about that if I were an ancient person on that moon?

There is also a question about how much really this moon is life supporting considering its close distance to the planet. Could intelligent life like us be developing and thriving there?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding. Some of your question are valid, some other are hard to understand and others are opinion based. All together they make your question too broad. Please limit yourself to one question per post, and strive to write that question as clear as possible, and calling for factual asnwers, not opinion based.

Comment: [Hope this will help](http://www.worlddreambank.org/P/PEG.HTM)